# How to update values in a dictionary using value parameters(not using keys) in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary value as follows;(For example key= keyA)

```
{'state': 'unprocessed', 'date_populated': '2017-09-26 02:07:58.535131', 'site': 'Site1'}
```

I want to update the '**state**' parameter in the value to '**processed**'.

How can I do that?

I know I can update like

```
cacheDictionary.update({keyA:'newValue'})
```

But in the above approach I will miss my timestamps. I need to keep that timestamps and only update **state** parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Reassign

Just reassign it. `dictionary["state"] = "processed"`.

`dictionary.update(insert)` will add all of the `key: value` pairs in `insert`, which is not what you want.

You can also do `dictionary.update({"state": "processed"})`, which overwrites it.

Essentially, `dictionary.update(insert)` is equivalent to saying `for key in insert.keys(): dictionary[key] = insert[key]`